# Regular expression to capture a String and Number

Tags: java, regex, json

I'm trying to get a regular expression for:

`{"Place": "DENMARK", "ID": "9513436", "trains_used": 3, "Current": "_ ___ ____"}`

to get the output as this:

`DENMARK 9513436 3 "_ ___ ____"`

But I'm not getting how to capture the whole word. Can anybody give me the regular expression for this?

EDIT: Yes it is a JSON string. But I don't know JSON
EDIT: I'm trying to use string.split() in Java.

Comment: Wait. Is that a JSON String?

Comment: If its a JSON string, why don't you just use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)?

Comment: Take a look at [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/detail?name=google-gson-2.2.2-release.zip&can=2&q=gson) for parsing a json string.

Comment: Never use a regex for this, use a library to handle it. There's a full example using different Jackson and GSon libraries here: [Java JSON Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-json-tutorials/). Make some tests and decide the better for you.

Comment: Agree - if this is JSON, you aren't looking for a regex.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza And others: Thank you. I'll go through the tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String teststr = "{\"Place\": \"DENMARK\", \"ID\": \"9513436\", \"trains_used\": 3, \"Current\": \"_ ___ ____\"}";

String regex = ".*?: \"(.*?)\".*?: \"(.*?)\".*?: (.*?),.*?: (\".*?\")";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(teststr);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2) + " " + m.group(3) + " " + m.group(4));
}
```